# Can you avoid fees while self representing

Tags: united-states, real-estate, fees

I am a self representing buyer,  the property I am interested in purchasing located in Indiana USA, is under list contract.  The seller has an agent for the property.

As I self represent myself and submit an offer with the required paper work : mortgage approval letter, purchase agreement and Earnest money, does the seller still pay 4 percent fees to his/her realtor since they have a listing contract?

Comment: Real-estate transactions vary from country to country and in the US, even from State to State. So, _some_ indication of _where_ you are planning on buying the property would be helpful. A generic response of "Tell me about all possible locations" will likely result in your question being closed as too broad. Oh, and it is _earnest money_ not Ernest money even if you are in Oscar Wlide's play The Importance of Being Earnest"!

Comment: @dilip ;) thank you for the feedback and made appropriate changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does the seller still pay 4 percent fees to his/her realtor since they
> have a listing contract?

What happens between the seller and their agent depends on the terms of their contract. Unless they show you the contract you won't know if the rate is 4% or something else. They could have a contract that allows a discount if the seller finds the buyer, they could also have a contract that still charges the full amount if the buyer doesn't have an agent.